# Python win32api.SetCursorPos Error

Tags: python, windows, pywin32

When I run this line of code:

```
def mousePos(cord):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x_pad + cord[0], y_pad + cord[1]))
```

I am getting an error that I don't understand.

```
line 55, in mousePos
win32api.SetCursorPos((x_pad + cord[0], y_pad + cord[1]))
pywintypes.error: (0, 'SetCursorPos', 'No error message is available')
```

Can anyone help me clear this up?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you print the tuple that you're passing to SetCursorPos?

Comment: If parameters are passed correctly, it depends on the context. For example, if you're trying to click somewhere while Security Confirmation (UAC) dialog is open, this function will always fail and you can't workaround it by OS design. Please provide more details about what you're trying.